Usage of ではないのか + 知れないけれども in this sentence?

花岡: 理解とは、死んだら、ということだろうか？


笑って言った花岡に陰惨な影はなくて、だから本気ではないのかも知れないけれども。　

So the character makes says about "Maybe you will understand the truth after you die! (the truth of the afterline)
Then the narration thinks this:

笑って言った花岡に陰惨な影はなくて

There is no shadow of sadness in Hanaoka

だから本気ではないのかも知れないけれども。　

Is this meant to be a positive?
"She may not be serious?" It may be that she's serious?" "So I wonder if she's serious?"


本気ではない means "she is not serious".
～のかもしれない is made of an explanatory-の and かもしれない, so it means "it may be that ～".

見たのかもしれない。 He may have seen it.
猫なのかもしれない。 It may be that it's a cat.


けれども means "..., though" or "..., but...".

Thus the combined meaning is:

だから本気ではないのかも知れないけれども。　
So it may be that she is not serious, though.
→ So she may not be serious, though.

